# Get visible items when scrolling in a LazyList

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I have a LazyList and I have to load item information of those items visible on screen. Every time a new item is visible (because the user scrolled) it should load the item information. What would be the right approach?

I know `LazyGridState` / `LazyListState` have `layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo` but I'm more concerned about the way to consume this information.

I suppose I should use a `LaunchedEffect` to trigger my "callback" but what should be the *key*? the "listState"? Or should I use a `derivedStateOf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a side-effect to know what are the visible items in any time.

Something like:

```
LaunchedEffect(visibleItemIds){
   //doSomething()
}

val state = rememberLazyListState()
val visibleItemIds: List<Int> by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        val layoutInfo = state.layoutInfo
        val visibleItemsInfo = layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo
        if (visibleItemsInfo.isEmpty()) {
            emptyList()
        } else {
            visibleItemsInfo.map { it.index }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `visibleItemsInfo` returns also the partially visible items.

Comment: the `ifEmpty` check is not necessary, is it?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible implementation I came up with:

```
LaunchedEffect(listState) {
    snapshotFlow { listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo }
        .map { it.map { it.index } }
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .collectLatest {
            //list
        }
}
```

where "listState" is `val listState = rememberLazyGridState()`